# locale django model Float Field to comma separated

Tags: django, django-models

is there any simple way to make a models.FloatField comma(not dot) separated? Without defining new format kind?

My settings.py are already localized, but still accept only dots

`LANGUAGE_CODE = 'de-De', 

USE_I18N = True,

USE_L10N = True`

Answer (score 2):

Add a parameter `localize=True` to your field declaration.

See: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/forms/fields/#localize

Answer (score 2):

Field accepts it, but the model doesn't. There is no 'localize'-parameter in models. (i.e. `space = models.FloatField()`)

Comment: doesn't matter... in the db you can have anything, important is what you presenting to the user.

Answer (score 0):

> doesn't matter... in the db you can have anything, important is what you presenting to the user

No.

form:

```
cost = forms.CharField(localize=True)
```

POST:

```
cost    u'300000,0'
```

> Exception Type:   ValueError
>
> Exception Value:invalid literal for int()
>   with base 10: ''

Answer (score 0):

I say Jerzyk is right, BUT I found it a big pain creating a separate form for each model (most of them are admin-generated and I want to save work). So I created a simple jQuery fix. It requires overwriting of `admin/base.html` (you have to make sure following js file is loaded on EACH page).

```
    //enter each Floatfield that you have in models.py as input[type=text][name=FIELD_NAME]
    grp.jQuery(document).ready(function () {
grp.jQuery("input[type=text][name=time],input[type=text][name=default_charge]").keypress(function (e) {

    if (e.keyCode == 44){
        var myval = grp.jQuery(this).val();
        console.log(myval+".")
        grp.jQuery(this).val(myval+".")
        return false;
    }
})
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using ModelForms, you can set the list of localized fields:

```
    class MyModelForm(BaseModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ("user", "cost", "currency")
            localized_fields = ('cost',)
```

If you want that all fields are localized then use `ALL_FIELDS`

```
    from django.forms import ALL_FIELDS

    class MyModelForm(BaseModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = MyModel
            fields = ("user", "cost", "currency")
            localized_fields = ALL_FIELDS
```